# Prove $\ker \phi=\langle 1+\sqrt{-5}, 2\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Let $\phi:\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]\to\mathbb{Z}_2$
$$\phi(p+q\sqrt{-5})=[p+q]_2$$

I want to prove $\ker \phi=\langle 1+\sqrt{-5}, 2\rangle$

So what I did:

$m=p+q\sqrt{5}\in \ker \phi\Longleftrightarrow [p+q]_2=[0]_2\Longleftrightarrow $ $p+q\in 2\mathbb{Z}$

So now how can I continue? Any hint?

Comment: Hint: $p+q \sqrt{5} = p + p \sqrt{5} - p \sqrt{5} + q \sqrt{5} = p (1 + \sqrt{5}) - (p-q) \sqrt{5}$. Now note $p - q \equiv p + q \pmod{2}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to prove that every element $p+q\sqrt{5}$ from the kernel is in $\langle 1+\sqrt{5}, 2\rangle$. Since $p+q$ is even,
$p-q$ is also even, $=2n$ for some integer $n$. Then $p+q\sqrt{5}=n\cdot 2+q(1+\sqrt{5})$ as desired.

Answer (score 4):

Clearly $\phi(1+\sqrt{5}) = 0$ and $\phi(2)=0$. Hence
$$\langle 1+\sqrt{5}, 2\rangle\subset \ker(\phi).$$
Suppose $a+b\sqrt{5}$ is in kernel. Then $a+b = 2k$ for some $k$. If both $a$ and $b$ are even, then $a+b\sqrt{5}=2\left(a/2+b/2\sqrt{5}\right) \in \langle1+\sqrt{5}, 2\rangle     $.

If both are odd, then $a+b\sqrt{5} = 1+\sqrt{5}+(a-1)+(b-1)\sqrt{5} \in  \langle1+\sqrt{5}, 2\rangle$ as $(a-1)$ and $(b-1)$ are even. In any case
$$\ker(\phi) \subset  \langle1+\sqrt{5}, 2\rangle.$$

And the conclusion follows.